# "pywintypes.error: (2, 'ShellExecute'," error after while True loop

Tags: loops, while-loop, pywin32

So im new to python scripting. And i was trying to make a script that scans a folder for PDF's if found it makes a temporary copy of it and then prints the file using my default printer. When the PDF is printed it will delete the temporary file and moves the original PDF to another folder. When i was testing the script before adding the "while True" loop it was working fine.

After adding the "while True" loop it prints all the PDF's in the folder, but as soon as there are no PDF's left it gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PDFCrop/PDFAutoPrint.py", line 26, in <module>
    win32api.ShellExecute(0, "printto", print_path, '"' + printer_name + '"', ".", 0)
pywintypes.error: (2, 'ShellExecute', 'Het systeem kan het opgegeven bestand niet vinden.')
```

Rough translation: "System cannot find the designated file"

The reason why i want the script to loop is that: as soon as a new file is in the folder it must automatically print it immediatly.

This is my script. Be gentle please. This is my second day of scripting with alot of help from google and StackOverflow :p

```
import os
import shutil
import win32api
import win32print
import time
import tempfile

# paden van de map waar de PDF's staan en de map waar de afgedrukte PDF's naartoe moeten worden verplaatst
pdf_dir = r'C:/Users/truid/Downloads/Bijgesneden Verzendlabels'
printed_dir = r'C:/Users/truid/Downloads/Geprinte Labels'

# krijg alle PDF-bestanden in de map
pdf_files = [f for f in os.listdir(pdf_dir) if f.endswith('.pdf')]

# haal de standaardprinter op
printer_name = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()

# loop door de PDF-bestanden heen en druk ze af
while True:
    for pdf_file in pdf_files:
        if pdf_file.endswith('.pdf'):
            print_path = os.path.join(pdf_dir, pdf_file)
            time.sleep(2)
        
            # gebruik ShellExecute om het PDF-bestand af te drukken
            win32api.ShellExecute(0, "printto", print_path, '"' + printer_name + '"', ".", 0)
            print(f"Het bestand {pdf_file} is afgedrukt op {printer_name}")
            time.sleep(3)
            
            # verplaats het afgedrukte PDF-bestand naar de map met afgedrukte PDF's
            printed_path = os.path.join(printed_dir, pdf_file)
            shutil.move(print_path, printed_path)
            print(f"Het bestand {pdf_file} is verplaatst")
    time.sleep(5)
    print(f"Aan het zoeken.")
type here
```

Tried alot of stuff, but it all broke my script even more...